Как правильно сконвертировать сущности из DTO в DB в EF Core для работы с БД?
Помогите разобраться, есть следующие DB-сущности
class UserDb
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public Guid IdCompany {get; set;}
    public CompanyDb Company {get; set;}
}

class CompanyDb
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<UserDb> Users {get; set;}
}

и dto
class UserDTO
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}

    public Guid IdCompany {get; set;}
    public CompanyDto Company {get; set;}
}

class CompanyDto
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public List<UserDTO> Users {get; set;}
}

есть некий контролер, одним из действий которого надо создать и сохранить компанию, но я не понимаю как это сделать? Как правильно добавить в компанию список Dto пользователей а потом сконвертировать их в сущности БД и сохранить? Кто может подсказать, как правильно?
[HttPost]
public void CreateCompany(CompanyDto)
{

}





Вопрос не ясен. Вы не знаете как создавать экземпляры класссов? Или вопрос про то как «правильно»? Вообще если вам надо одни сущности отразить на другие, используется маппер, например такой https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html
